# WSO2 API Manager Gateway clustering. How to setup gateway endpoint in api-manager.xml

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have a plan to use WSO2 API manager for my company, so trying to make it work clustering.

it consists of Keymanager, Gateway(manager, worker), Publisher, Store on 2 AWS instances.

Host1 contains Keymanager, Gateway manager, Publisher, Store.
Host2 contains Gateway worker.

the point that I'm confusing is how to configure correct setting for  in the /repository/conf/api-manager.xml file.

Case 1) set gateway.manager.com in GatewayEndpoint

```
<APIGateway>
  . . . 
    <ServerURL>https://gateway.manager.com:9444/services/</ServerURL>
    <Username>admin</Username>
    <Password>admin</Password>
    <GatewayEndpoint>http://gateway.manager.com:8281, https://gateway.manager.com:8244</GatewayEndpoint>
. . .
</APIGateway>
```

Case 2) set gateway.worker.com in GatewayEndpoint

```
<APIGateway>
  . . . 
    <ServerURL>https://gateway.manager.com:9444/services/</ServerURL>
    <Username>admin</Username>
    <Password>admin</Password>
    <GatewayEndpoint>http://gateway.worker.com:8280, https://gateway.worker.com:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
. . .
 </APIGateway>
```

---

hosts
200.100.100.123 gateway.manager.com
200.100.100.234 gateway.worker.com

---

Thanks, Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to APIGateway configuration on Gateway Manager, since you are using Gateway Manager, Key Manager, Publisher, Store in one node.

You can configure you Gateway Manager node as below

```
<APIGateway>
    <Environments>
        <Environment type="hybrid">
        ...
            <ServerURL>https://gateway.manager.com:9443/services/</ServerURL> <!-- To deploy API to gateway Manager -->
            <Username>admin</Username>
            <Password>admin</Password> 
            <GatewayEndpoint>http://gateway.worker.com:8280,https://gateway.worker.com:8243</GatewayEndpoint> <!-- To show the gateway worker URLs for API in API Store -->
        </Environment>
    </Environments> 
    ...
</APIGateway>
```

You don't need to configure anything on Gateway Worker Node.

Comment: Thx your reply. for the first time when I modified "api-manager.xml", I thought GatewayEndpoint was just URL like you commented, however API  Console test worked well in case Case1, didn't worked in case Case2.
it makes me crazy...

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to define gateway manager URL in gateway endpoints section. Gateway endpoints section will be used at API store to list API gateway URLs when you click on API and see details. So you can use following configurations for all nodes without any issue.

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://gateway.worker.com:8280, https://gateway.worker.com:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
```

You need to define gateway server URL as follows in publisher mainly because it will  use this URL to publish API to gateway manager.

```
<ServerURL>https://gateway.manager.com:9444/services/</ServerURL>
```

Comment: thx for your quick reply, but there is an issue. 
When I set Case 2 for GatewayEndpoint, API console test in API Store return error code. ( no content , no response from server ).
When I set Case1 for GatewayEndpoint, API console test in API Store works well ( it returns response code 200 with correct values).
in case Case1, I am not sure if worker node is working. 
so I thought GatewayEndpoint is the most important point during configring.

Comment: Before you use API console please try to paste gateway worker pass through transport URL (https://gateway.worker.com:8243) in your browser and let browser to handle client certificate exchange. Or you can paste API invocation URL in browser and hit enter one time. Then you will be able to access API using API console.

Comment: thanks, I got this problem fixed. Gateway worker nodes return correct response.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks