# WSO2 Publisher/Store api-manager.xml config GatewayEndpoint with gateway clustering

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

If i have multiple gateway worker nodes, how can i config the GatewayEndpoint?

I read the post of [setup gateway endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872249/wso2-api-manager-gateway-clustering-how-to-setup-gateway-endpoint-in-api-manage), it that case just has one gateway worker node. I also had nginx node before WSO2 clustering, so we also need to display final endpoint URL in store to end users. for ServerURL, i can config it as url: "https://mgt.gw.devzone.com/services/" .

```
<APIGateway>
   <Environments>
       <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
            <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
            <Description>This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic.</Description>          
            <ServerURL>https://<API-Gateway-Host>:9443/services/</ServerURL>
            <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
            <Password>${admin.password}</Password>          
            <GatewayEndpoint>http://<API-Gateway-Host>:8280,https://<API-Gateway-Host>:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
       </Environment>
   </Environments>
</APIGateway>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes for the **ServerURL** you should point to the **GW Manager** node. When specifying the GW worker URLs you need to point to NginX. The GatewayEndpoint you are including here should resolve to NginX and NginX will loadbalance the request between the worker nodes. The URL you add here will be shown in the API Store.

Comment: Due to i install all components in one server, how about the port offset for gateway endpoint?

Comment: Yes you can add a Port off set to each GW, But this will not affect the Final GW worker URLs since in the URL you have to add the Port NginX is listening to.